# Pygame - can't load images in a loop. Works without a loop

Tags: python, image, pygame, load

I've got another problem, tried many other ways to do it, none of them worked in a loop but they did work individually.

In folder Game I have a file which opens the game. Then in subfolder images I've got all the images I want to draw on my screen using Pygame.

```
|Game
|start_game.py
|- images
|       |
|       image0.png
|       image1.png
|       image2.png
```

When I try to load images one by one and code works all right:

```
image0 = pygame.image.load(os.getcwd() + '\images\image0.png')
image1 = pygame.image.load(os.getcwd() + '\images\image1.png')
...
```

But to make it easier to use a code I want to use for loop to change the numbers of .png files.

```
images=[]
for num in range(3):
    image = pygame.image.load(os.getcwd() + '\images\image{num}.png')
    images.append(image)
```

And here I got traceback:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

How can I import it in a for loop without an error?

Comment: You forgot the `.format()` to convert `{num}`.  Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp  While you're fixing that, maybe you could also consider using `os.path.join()` rather than embedding OS-dependent path separators.

Comment: `'\images\image{num}.png'` -> `f'\images\image{num}.png'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a f-string. Try this:

```
images=[]
for num in range(3):
    image = pygame.image.load(os.getcwd() + f'\images\image{num}.png')
    images.append(image)
```

You were getting 3 times the string '\images\image{num}.png' instead of what you wanted.